# control how interaction term in effect plot is displayed

Tags: r, plot, effects, interaction, mixed-models

I am trying to plot an interaction term from a linear mixed effects model using the effects plot. See example below:

```
library(nlme)
fitA <- lme(PEE ~ Pupper*max_depth,
  random=~1 + Pupper|ref, data=m4,
  cor=corAR1(), method="ML")
```

`Pupper` is a continuous variable and `max_depth` is a factorial variable (5 levels - 400,500,600,700,800).

When I plot model output in an effects plot with an interaction term I am able to show how the relationship between `PEE` and `Pupper` changes according to the different factors levels of `max_depth`:

```
library(effects)
plot(effect("Pupper*max_depth",fitA),
  xlab=expression(paste("d"[-5]," P"[upper]," (m"^" -1",")")),
  ylab=expression(paste("PEE rate (h"^" -1",")")),      
        factor.names=FALSE, layout=c(5,1), alternating=FALSE, 
     main="A", ticks.x=list(Pupper=list(at=seq(0.4,1.0,0.2))), 
   ##layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow=TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3), TRUE)
        rotx=45, more=FALSE, grid=FALSE, lwd=1)
```

[image: plot1]

However, sometimes when I plot a similar model the effects plot will change how I want the interaction to be displayed (see below). In the effects plot below, the plot 'decides' to display the relationship between `PEE` and `max_depth` and how this changes according to some arbitrary division of the continuous variable `Pupper` (labeled `Plower` in code and 'k150' in the plot shown below):

```
fitB <- lme(PEE ~ Plower*max_depth,
   random=~1 + Plower|ref, data=m4, 
   cor=corAR1(), method="ML")

plot(effect("Plower*max_depth",fitB),
xlab=expression(paste("d"[-5]," P"[lower]," (m"^" -1",")")), 
ylab=expression(paste("PEE rate (h"^" -1",")")),        
factor.names=FALSE, layout=c(5,1), alternating=FALSE,
  main="A", ticks.x=list(Plower=list(at=seq(0.4,1.0,0.2))), 
 ##layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow=TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3), TRUE)
rotx=45, more=FALSE, grid=FALSE, lwd=1)
```

[image: plot2]

However, I am interested in how the factor `max_depth` influences the relationship between `PEE` and `Plower` (similar to the first figure above). I cannot work out why the *effect* function displays the same interaction term in two different ways. I would love to know how to control the way an interaction term is represented in an effect plot as this problem keeps popping its ugly head up.

Below is a subset of my dataset:

```
structure(list(ref = c("2012-3corrige", "2011-28", "2011-26", 
"2011-21", "2011-21", "2013-7", "2012-1corrige", "2012-6corrige", 
"2013-4", "2011-21", "2013-10", "2013-4", "2013-13", "2011-26", 
"2013-11", "2012-3corrige", "2013-1", "2012-14corrige", "2013-1", 
"2011-27", "2012-6corrige", "2011-18", "2011-26", "2010-18", 
"2012-14corrige", "2011-21", "2013-6", "2013-11", "2011-27", 
"2011-18", "2012-16corrige", "2013-5", "2013-13", "2011-21", 
"2012-14corrige", "2013-5", "2013-18", "2012-16corrige", "2011-28", 
"2010-18", "2011-21", "2013-2", "2012-2corrige", "2013-4", "2013-5", 
"2013-11", "2011-21", "2013-6", "2011-28", "2013-6", "2010-18", 
"2011-21", "2013-18", "2011-16", "2012-11corrige", "2011-28", 
"2011-27", "2012-3corrige", "2012-2corrige", "2013-3", "2012-1corrige", 
"2012-14corrige", "2012-14corrige", "2013-10", "2012-6corrige", 
"2010-18", "2012-11corrige", "2013-7", "2013-2", "2012-16corrige", 
"2013-1", "2013-18", "2012-16corrige", "2013-6", "2012-4corrige", 
"2013-4", "2013-10", "2013-3", "2013-2", "2011-16", "2012-1corrige", 
"2011-21", "2011-21", "2013-18", "2013-3", "2011-26", "2010-18", 
"2013-13", "2012-6corrige", "2013-3", "2012-16corrige", "2012-15corrige", 
"2011-28", "2012-6corrige", "2012-6corrige", "2012-11corrige", 
"2013-1", "2013-11", "2012-11corrige", "2013-6"), Pupper = c(0.861958207287982, 
0.824829924556841, 0.958739109455748, 0.935401831656677, 0.955566680038604, 
0.948368978826279, 0.745071680369673, 0.827539122942233, 0.726448658429027, 
0.943103302931338, 0.858445846226439, 0.784802718309937, 0.881010495586365, 
0.911770168408684, 0.90971638692581, 1.02155421458351, 0.851778844536538, 
1.1553118943962, 0.887452083213511, 0.8218157295485, 0.871777265131409, 
0.829892474962871, 1.01579427707254, 0.715539162683171, 1.12624787680155, 
0.713105471394893, 0.802478037082636, 0.773243110590944, 0.762028205952159, 
0.785089166910358, 0.844285844170484, 0.887514023676371, 0.870367623478723, 
0.820303824472643, 0.636099278958915, 0.953776661488422, 0.816485694234068, 
0.861493535070196, 0.787945463425822, 0.918041865421543, 0.877275056321815, 
0.624152855209897, 0.971197595182818, 0.769613695304339, 0.941443459091764, 
0.929070549770906, 1.031203743205, 0.692597025693873, 0.846978945035432, 
0.72446749179426, 0.541564092852052, 0.744921803502444, 0.917786983273715, 
0.702051561892398, 0.975310403563878, 0.808819367281032, 0.858040403089116, 
0.741495941398947, 0.698143566897239, 0.979366380200314, 0.992046903013047, 
0.995331870590213, 0.804437082665078, 0.8307554779262, 0.878549524310762, 
0.654725061889849, 0.93024953667308, 0.654611447094126, 0.689696271315618, 
0.77302453480932, 0.916283427766758, 0.894114399839305, 0.840205756601608, 
0.767235548359607, 0.831544386468135, 0.685089269122402, 0.860269828471148, 
0.895228365651283, 0.785946885397904, 0.812567650516969, 0.797256286689962, 
0.800979891549511, 0.684467773772683, 0.846228645225391, 0.801015938251751, 
0.964375424821682, 0.783654311543043, 0.951249150678552, 0.847095453102345, 
0.782862048298847, 0.897798965949478, 0.79591714811698, 0.954852044385237, 
0.885914708711347, 0.789575506205708, 1.10814372714012, 0.875651148193922, 
0.851523408695002, 0.963324355206144, 0.795071091161036), Plower = c(0.705132769215998, 
0.667302197075824, 0.629978835623335, 0.632452896796802, 0.641619045851976, 
0.634150350206216, 0.521875889886134, 0.69048678481199, 0.620155894379255, 
0.72673011955379, 0.644805071164551, 0.691418831100224, 0.561990510002912, 
0.702502669034076, 0.5885329988032, 1.06019049650942, 0.610499795249761, 
0.863589408611907, 0.671649710290516, 0.7008237216939, 0.613070958372683, 
0.52121652570373, 0.743727100487806, 0.619214556245787, 1.0217109832694, 
0.653199816289013, 0.653255947797901, 0.629436452185155, 0.621227279933305, 
0.581484689776476, 0.605084016204913, 0.670828674932066, 0.694246594037978, 
0.732994239783339, 0.728155423409921, 0.657673931367209, 0.681945582710071, 
0.656113353702447, 0.55299186250794, 0.589741939797023, 0.760512984767519, 
0.550684422635445, 0.888934443277143, 0.615143614667881, 0.736486026117717, 
0.616589579139919, 0.640405340389975, 0.618517043688639, 0.612475849864031, 
0.681245183469212, 0.642477842246546, 0.683125578173995, 0.636702442275825, 
0.568741300299764, 0.681781639762194, 0.58956858049858, 0.697614984548545, 
0.773372843818268, 0.599073358520381, 0.653548263966276, 0.846172099647715, 
0.946825538132655, 0.635504629303462, 0.61980005655224, 0.594418483337567, 
0.610786378368084, 0.809715477703094, 0.596886365511337, 0.601414998150196, 
0.680138336678131, 0.672368946338244, 0.693205917779446, 0.736742863266092, 
0.636678882954351, 0.611664395999418, 0.630585706572337, 0.6554630468205, 
0.617362130357864, 0.615793526002561, 0.688748462389895, 0.733587834625896, 
0.715468455706547, 0.695921451506322, 0.649384323802169, 0.654685675216232, 
0.675344356606317, 0.617759392212426, 0.620895052860519, 0.652138022200822, 
0.638494322605926, 0.798451637031189, 0.884450865414997, 0.895823643358446, 
0.661857655055493, 0.743487278528243, 0.88302132854573, 0.660494764046872, 
0.638155299450374, 0.515272975866573, 0.636047692132176), PEE = c(1.49625537031302, 
0.579708304983786, 1.09755665230733, 0.79999598579792, 0.366971323405136, 
0.534519852186464, 0.892172302701565, 0.764300080784289, 0.162161584516302, 
1.05547854644252, 1.75994722974226, 0.502090519778478, 0.813556191910923, 
0.72071830101183, 0.124737712452804, 0.24096278221797, 2.11763754191128, 
0.0970872140009704, 0.214668546888839, 0.997227687637828, 0.449413221941473, 
0.445533213208998, 0.719422276286327, 0.311417756794472, 0.0799998795735146, 
0.836011454943211, 0.217381544231536, 0.131863894834852, 1.1881086717854, 
0.562478645146688, 2.13755423670725, 0.260855398500945, 0.769228719926564, 
0.792077729637109, 0.46631964160662, 0.727219913477435, 0.234599414042217, 
1.24135448496734, 1.73912823566756, 0.437157161658986, 1.18491673172712, 
1.57894265236866, 0.325374033367569, 0.133629870488068, 0.260855348600893, 
0.279711624960117, 1.04650548272943, 1.13790951622142, 0.512819441159373, 
2.51301278595252, 0.948078086013639, 0.183485515251287, 0.521708195407091, 
0.834371581292816, 0.907354231373586, 0.263735732207326, 0.94736384877553, 
0.865382874911045, 0.162378076290205, 1.80685106084338, 1.07131194190618, 
1.20567188480079, 1.01009693910426, 0.352933736835024, 0.315767760495837, 
0.901500577761704, 1.08481956174672, 0.553504151294972, 1.81542854475215, 
2.23136249824668, 0.14018646847029, 0.58250584995577, 1.74754206600435, 
0.404021461283339, 1.0507621403718, 3.1578487818322, 1.23592560921063, 
0.428569941841892, 2.59927399028359, 0.462953155929056, 1.60334686111772, 
0.610996390428844, 0.93749693604517, 0.374210416022193, 0.596024133599949, 
1.07142175386991, 0.233917466116807, 0.773637607411201, 0.733915433670645, 
0.693195231932592, 0.699678270730694, 0.75104196328333, 1.1707299559812, 
0.376558572007052, 1.5725384212365, 0.17424722659426, 0.481925512179189, 
0.127383975172354, 0.449990814000021, 0.828701950628209), max_depth = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("400", "500", "600", "700", "800"), class = "factor"), 
    fangle = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("0", "20", "40", "60"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ref", 
"Pupper", "Plower", "PEE", "max_depth", "fangle"), row.names = c(26297L, 
18163L, 13367L, 10757L, 10813L, 43605L, 22984L, 27608L, 39808L, 
11220L, 32882L, 39987L, 35960L, 13719L, 34174L, 25877L, 31747L, 
19402L, 31394L, 14990L, 28537L, 9023L, 13684L, 1781L, 19411L, 
9964L, 41834L, 33800L, 15277L, 8673L, 21864L, 40681L, 35425L, 
11590L, 19901L, 40867L, 36845L, 21698L, 18302L, 470L, 11459L, 
37414L, 24555L, 40026L, 40578L, 33627L, 9525L, 41816L, 17695L, 
42057L, 294L, 9972L, 37137L, 8304L, 19086L, 15817L, 15351L, 26097L, 
24896L, 39059L, 23703L, 20110L, 19937L, 32121L, 28556L, 13L, 
19157L, 42865L, 37922L, 21887L, 31638L, 37008L, 21905L, 41848L, 
26621L, 39864L, 32870L, 39107L, 37721L, 7969L, 23826L, 11903L, 
12024L, 36500L, 38488L, 13287L, 462L, 36245L, 28096L, 38611L, 
21500L, 20565L, 17140L, 27772L, 27773L, 18897L, 30992L, 34564L, 
18553L, 41312L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code and see the results ourselves. Even if you don't have enough rep to inline images, you can upload them to imgur.com and include the link. A higher rep user can include them for you.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. I have given a sample of input data to run the code. Hopefully this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The data subset you've supplied are insufficient to fit the models but I think that I can answer your question. The selection of the variable on the horizontal axis is controlled by the `x.var` argument to `plot.eff()`; from `?plot.eff`:

> `x.var`:   the index (number) or quoted name of the covariate or factor to
>   place on the horizontal axis of each panel of the effect plot. The
>   default is the predictor with the largest number of levels or values.

In turn, the covariate values at which an effect is evaluated is controlled by the `xlevels` argument to `Effect()`, which in your case is called by `effect()`; from `?Effect`:

> `xlevels`: this argument is used to set the number of levels for any
>   focal predictor that is not a factor. If xlevels=NULL, the default,
>   then the number and values of levels for any numeric predictor is
>   determined by grid.pretty. If xlevels=n is an integer, then each
>   numeric predictor is represented by n equally spaced levels. More
>   generally, xlevels can be a named list of values at which to set each
>   numeric predictor. For example, xlevels=list(x1=c(2, 4, 7), x2=5)
>   would use the values 2, 4 and 7 for the levels of x1, 5 equally spaced
>   levels for the levels of x2, and use the default for any other numeric
>   predictors. If partial residuals are computed, then the focal
>   predictor that is to appear on the horizontal axis of an effect plot
>   is evaluated at 100 equally spaced values along its full range, and,
>   by default, other numeric predictors are evaluated at the quantiles
>   specified in the quantiles argument, unless their values are given
>   explicitly in xlevels.

Curiously, the second plot that you show appears to include a variable, `k150`, that doesn't appear in the model.

I hope this helps,

John

Comment: Thanks for all your help John. The variable 'k150' is suppose to read 'Plower'. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: For anyone else wondering, the x.var argument is used as follows: x.var="k150"